# Retrieve a data from mongodb to angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mongodb

My mongorepository

```
 import org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.MongoRepository;

public interface RecordRepository extends MongoRepository<Record, String> {
}
```

My model:

```
public class Record {

private long id;
private String cameraid;

@JsonSerialize(using=DateTimeSerial.class)
private DateTime timestamp;
private String filename;


public Record(long id,String cameraid, DateTime timestamp, String filename) {
    this.id=id;
    this.cameraid = cameraid;
    this.timestamp = timestamp;
    this.filename = filename;
} //getters and setters
```

My controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value="list") //controller for list
public List<Record> getList() {
        List<Record> recordList = rep.findAll(); 


        return recordList;
}
}
```

My data in mongodb

```
{"id":1,"cameraid":"001","timestamp":"2016/06/15 15:03","filename":"e997a7321a3d2966802ba466feca69f8"},
{"id":2,"cameraid":"001","timestamp":"2016/06/15 15:03","filename":"63999edc2218f490cd883592fe5d26a1"},
{"id":3,"cameraid":"002","timestamp":"2016/06/15 15:03","filename":"9ba6722aed8aa1aae0e4545ee6d376c3"},
```

My html file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app='camListApp'>
<head>

<style>
#myDIV {
width: 500px;
height: 500px;
position: relative;
right: 20px;
top: 90px;
}

table, th, td {
border: 1px solid black;
border-collapse: collapse;
}
</style>
<script     src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.0/angular.min.js"> 
</script>
<script src="hello.js"></script>
<title>Image viewer </title>
</head>

<body>
<h3>Search by cameraid:</h3><br>
<select ng-model="searchBox" style="width:25%">
<option value="000000006f4280af">{{record.cameraid}}</option>
</select>


<div ng-controller="Hello">

<br>
 <table style="width:50%">
    <thead>
      <tr>

        <th>CamID</th>
        <th>Timestamp</th>
        <th>View Image</th>

      </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>

      <tr ng-repeat="record in records | filter:searchBox | orderBy:'+timestamp'">

        <td>{{record.cameraid}}</td>
        <td>{{record.timestamp}}</td>
        <td><button ng-click="toggleCustom()" onclick="myFunction()">View</button></td>

      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
   <span id="myDIV" ng-hide="custom"><img src="" width="300" height="300">
    </span>

    <!--<span ng-hide="custom">To:
        <input type="text" id="to" />
    </span>-->
    <span ng-show="custom"></span>
  </div>
  <script>
function myFunction() {
document.getElementById("myDIV").style.position = "absolute";
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

My js file

```
var camListApp = angular.module('camListApp', []);
camListApp.controller('Hello', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http){

$scope.custom = true;
$scope.toggleCustom = function() {
   $scope.custom = ! $scope.custom;
};
$http.get('http://localhost:8081/camera/list').then(function(response) {
     console.log(response);
        $scope.records= response.data; 
    });
}]);
```

How can i retrieve two of my cameraid data "001" and "002" from mongodb to be shown on my dropdownlist using angularJS? "http://localhost:8081/camera/list" is listing all my data on my web service. Anybody can help me with my question?

Comment: Also show your server side code. Have you tried fetching the data from db?

Comment: What `console.log(response);` is giving you?

Comment: @titi23 i havent try getting those two cameraid on my dropdownlist because i got no idea on how to retrieve it.

Comment: @titi23 the console prompt me this : Object { data: Array[8], status: 200, headers: dd/<(), config: Object, statusText: "OK" }

Comment: So ` data: Array[8]` is having the data that you have shown in the question?

Comment: @titi23 yes got data display on my table but now i want to search my data with my cameraid "001" and "002"

Comment: This you want to do using mongodb or javascript?

Comment: @titi23 Both can be achieve?

Comment: You need to read [mongodb-find-doc](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/) to know how to do it in server side. Without your server side code, it's difficult to help you. If you can provide your server side code as well, it will be easier.

Comment: @titi23 Server side code is it my model and controller?

Comment: You are getting data after doing `$http.get('http://localhost:8081/camera/list')` right? Tell us what code is giving you the data?

Comment: @titi23 yes http://localhost:8081/camera/list is to display my data .

Answer (score 0):

Though your code depends on the server side but you can try this one. I hope it works. The entire server code is not present.
Js should be modified like this:

```
     var camListApp = angular.module('camListApp', []);
        camListApp.controller('Hello', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http){
var value1="001";
var value2="002";
                 $http.get('http://localhost:8081/camera/list?value1='+ value1+'&value2='+ value2).then(function(response) {
              console.log(response);
                    $scope.records= response.data;
                });
        }]);
```

In html in select element change it to **{{records.cameraid}}**

```
 @RequestMapping(value="list") //controller for list
    public List<Record> getList(@RequestParam("value1") String value1, @RequestParam("value2") String value2) {
            List<Record> recordList = new ArrayList<Record>(); 
 List<Record> valueRecord1=rep.findByCameraId(value1);

List<Record> valueRecord2=rep.findByCameraId(value2);
recordList.add(valueRecord1);
recordList.add(valueRecord2);
return recordList;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should return [Object](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_objects.asp) or [JSON](http://www.json.org/) string because `rep.findAll()` return an [Iterable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html) interface. For example with JSON using [Jackson ObjectMapper](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.3.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html) class:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
String output = "[]";
try {
    output = mapper.writeValueAsString(rep.findAll());
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
return output;
```